# How to make fabric.js canvas center be 0,0?

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm just starting with fabric.js and I wonder if there is a way to create a canvas in such a way that I can work with cartesian coordinates? For example, I want a circle that I create at (0,0) to show up in the center of my canvas that reaches from -400 to 400 on the x-axis and -400 to 400 on the y.axis, with higher values of y going up and higher values of x going right.

Is there a way to do that without translating every position by hand?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [originX](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#originX) and [originY](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#originY) attributes.

```
var obj = canvas.getObjects();
for (var i in obj) {
    obj[i].set({
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    });
}
canvas.renderAll();
```

Check this fiddle with examples: http://jsfiddle.net/1ow02gea/51/

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was asking for... I would like to change the coordinate system of the canvas itself in such a way that the point (0,0) is located at the center of the canvas (width/2, height/2). According to your FIddle, the circle's and text's coordinates should be (0,0) instead of (100,100) and still be in the center of the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the origin of the canvas element without introducing visual artifacts. What you can do is **pan** the canvas to a virtual "0,0" position. Bear in mind that you will have to adjust both `X_PAN_VALUE` and `Y_PAN_VALUE` to your specific use case.

```
canvas.viewportTransform[4] = X_PAN_VALUE;
canvas.viewportTransform[5] = Y_PAN_VALUE;
```

Better late than never ;)